# Is there a function to get the int value of the deque.begin() in c++ before erasing it?

Tags: c++, deque

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int main ()
{
  std::deque<int> mydeque;

  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
  for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) mydeque.push_back(i);

  int first = mydeque.begin(); //this gives me an error
  std::cout<<first<<endl; //expecting to print out 1 before I erase it from mydeque
  mydeque.erase(mydeque.begin());

  return 0;
}
```

I'm looking to print out the integer value of 1 which is the first value of mydeque before I want to erase it, is there any function that allows me to do so?

Comment: You can deference on the iterator like `*mydeque.begin()`, or use `mydeque.front()`.

Comment: mydeque.begin() return the iterator

Comment: oh okay, thank you, I'm a new c++ programmer and I'm learning

Comment: Yes, see [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) and the member functions `at`, `operator[]`, `front` or `back`. So you have direct access to the first element in the dqueue with `mydeque.at(0);` or `mydeque[0];` or `mydeque.front();`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/begin) method returns an *iterator*. You need to dereference that iterator to get the *value* it refers to:

`int first = *mydeque.begin();`

Otherwise, just use the [`front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front) method instead, which returns (a reference to) the 1st *value*:

`int first = mydeque.front();`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::deque<int> mydeque;

// set some values (from 1 to 10)
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) mydeque.push_back(i);

auto iter = mydeque.begin();
int first = *iter;
/*
    or 
    int first = *mydeque.begin();
    //
        mydeque.begin()  is iterator
    //
*/
std::cout << first << std::endl; //expecting to print out 1 before I erase it from mydeque
mydeque.erase(mydeque.begin());

return 0;
```

hope this helps

Comment: That's actually quite tedious. There's no need to go into the iterators and using auto (which is best not used) . C++ provides 2 inbuilt function for exact purpose this question is trying to achieve. I mentioned them in my answer. Using them will often be the best choice and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The following would be the most straightforward and best way to do the thing you are trying to do in your question.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <deque> 
using namespace std;

int main () { 

         std::deque<int> mydeque; // set some values (from 1 to 10)

         for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)                           
              mydeque.push_back(i); 
         int num = mydeque.front(); //returns the frontmost element without deleting it
         std::cout<<num;
         mydeque.pop_front();//deletes the first element from deque
         return 0; 
    }
```